# TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums8'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing my code out and following the book Starting Out with Python: Second Edition by Tony Gaddis for my COMS-170 at MCC and for some reason I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tcarroll/Desktop/123.py", line 36, in <module> 
     main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums8'
```

Here is my code:

```
def main(nums8):
    inFile = open('nums8.txt', 'r')

num1 = int(inFile.readline())
num2 = int(inFile.readline())
num3 = int(inFile.readline())
num4 = int(inFile.readline())
num5 = int(inFile.readline())
num6 = int(inFile.readline())
num7 = int(inFile.readline())
num8 = int(inFile.readline())
num9 = int(inFile.readline())
num10 = int(inFile.readline())
num11 = int(inFile.readline())
num12 = int(inFile.readline())
num13 = int(inFile.readline())
num14 = int(inFile.readline())
num15 = int(inFile.readline())
num16 = int(inFile.readline())
num17 = int(inFile.readline())
num18 = int(inFile.readline())
num19 = int(inFile.readline())
num20 = int(inFile.readline())
num21 = int(inFile.readline())
num22 = int(inFile.readline())

inFile.close()

total = int(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num12 + num13 + num14 + num15 + num16 + num17 + num18 + num19 + num20 + num21 + num22)

print('The numbers are: ', num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16, num17, num18, num19, num20, num21, num22)
print('Their total is: ', total)
main()
```

The question in the book is:
5. Sum of Numbers
Assume that a file containing a series of integers is named numbers.txt (for this assignment we actually had a file we downloaded and used) and exists on the computer's disk. Write a program that reads all of the numbers stored in the file and calculates their total.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong: Your last line calls main without an argument.

Comment: Aside: what if there are 23 numbers?  Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: This is not what the author of the book had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

just define your main func without an argument:

```
def main():
    inFile = open('nums8.txt', 'r')
```

Also, you want place your file reading code into this function too:

```
def main(nums8):
    inFile = open('nums8.txt', 'r')
    num1 = int(inFile.readline())
    num2 = int(inFile.readline())
    num3 = int(inFile.readline())
    num4 = int(inFile.readline())
    num5 = int(inFile.readline())
    num6 = int(inFile.readline())
    num7 = int(inFile.readline())
    num8 = int(inFile.readline())
    num9 = int(inFile.readline())
    num10 = int(inFile.readline())
    num11 = int(inFile.readline())
    num12 = int(inFile.readline())
    num13 = int(inFile.readline())
    num14 = int(inFile.readline())
    num15 = int(inFile.readline())
    num16 = int(inFile.readline())
    num17 = int(inFile.readline())
    num18 = int(inFile.readline())
    num19 = int(inFile.readline())
    num20 = int(inFile.readline())
    num21 = int(inFile.readline())
    num22 = int(inFile.readline())

    inFile.close()

    total = int(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num12 + num13 + num14 + num15 + num16 + num17 + num18 + num19 + num20 + num21 + num22)

    print('The numbers are: ', num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16, num17, num18, num19, num20, num21, num22)
    print('Their total is: ', total)

main()
```

Also you might want write this shorter:

```
def main():

    with open('nums8.txt') as inFile:
        nums = [int(line) for line in inFile]
    total = sum(nums)
    print('The numbers are: ', nums)
    print('Their total is: ', total)
```

This example is related with for-loop, list, list comprehensions, line-wise file reading, context managers ("with open(...)" stuff) and finding a sum of values in list. The good thing here is that it sums all lines in file and doesn't care about how much lines are there (zero or billion or more)

happy googling!

Comment: The second snippet is not only shorter, but actually solves the problem OP posted. There is no mention about the file containing exactly 22 lines.